# Null Value returned in java

Tags: java

```
package project;

/**
 * 
 * @author manish
 */
public class ClassA {
    String str;

    public void SerString(String _str) {
        str = _str;
    }

    public String GetString() {
        return str;
    }
}

package project;

/**
 * 
 * @author manish
 */
public class ClassB extends ClassA {

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    String strB;

    public void SerStringB(String _strB) {
        strB = _strB;
    }

    public String GetStringB() {
        return strB;
    }

    public String output() {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        return strB + a.GetString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassA A = new ClassA();
        A.SerString("data");
        ClassB B = new ClassB();
        B.SerStringB("firm");
        System.out.println(B.output());
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}
```

Output:  firmnull

I am supposed to get not null values. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new object inside the `output` method and that does not have a value for `a`. Try passing the object of `ClassA` created in `main` to the `output` method and use that object.

```
public String output(ClassA a)
{
    return strB+a.GetString();
}
```

and then in main call output as :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ClassA A = new ClassA();
  A.SerString("data");
  ClassB B = new ClassB();
  B.SerStringB("firm");
  System.out.println(B.output(A));        
  // TODO code application logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In output method of class B, you create an A object without pass the string value for its str (String). 
So, when you call a.GetString(), it returns null. 
Combine with strB, output method return "firmnull" 
That's your cause of your error, the fixing base on your business logic. 
In this case, you need to pass str value for a after creating , or pass an A object (with str value) to this method.